# Navbar data-toggle and data-target doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm trying to make a responsive navbar.
In desktop shows the NavItems in the NavBar, but in small devices shows the sandwich icon and when we click it should show the same NavItems.
However, when I click on the button, nothing happens.
I was making an adaption of this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUKJA6B1Xr4

The view look like this:

[small devices version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7l0g.png)

[desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VplMs.png)

My NavBar.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import NavItems from "./NavItems";
class NavBar extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-default panel-app">
                <div className="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-target="#nav-collapse">
                        <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Hoje para jantar</a>
                </div>
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
                    <NavItems className="nav navbar-nav" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in" href=""></NavItems>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    );
}
}
export default NavBar;
```

My NavItems.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class NavItems extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li className="nav navbar-brand"><a href="#">Receitas</a></li>
                <li className="nav navbar-brand"><a href="#">Por categoria</a></li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
export default NavItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to put the jquery link in the index.html file.
Now it works :)